# Cannot run a project/file on visual studio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, error-handling

I am beginner on c# when trying to run my program it gives this error:'The type or namespace name 'A' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?'

But i have all the files inside one folder.As u can see from pictures : [image][image][image]

Comment: Make the class A public.

Comment: @ Llazar i made same problem

Comment: A.cs may not be part of the build. make sure it is included in the project (csproj) and its build action is set to "compile".

Comment: again same error

Comment: Make a Clean and then a Build.

Comment: Add the namespace before the class initialization like `new oopexam.A()` maybe can work.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose Class A have a method call start(), if i'm right you should to make your method static as well, and delete parentheses next to the class.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        A.Start();
    }
}

class A
{
    public static void Start()
    {
       // Something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public access specifier should not be an issue, as I can see both classes has same namespace.
You can try-

1. Clean and rebuild
2. Try creating instance of class A with namespace
3. Restart visual studio